# compare the result of two selects on same table

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

Supposing I have a table, mytable, as follows:

```
sampleID   rs         A1    A2
--------------------------------
1001       rs123      A     C
1001       rs124      T     C
1001       rs125      A     T
1001       rs126      A     C
1002       rs122      A     C
1002       rs123      T     C
1002       rs124      T     C
1002       rs125      A     C
```

And I would like to compare any 2 sampleID's where they have a common rs value to see if their A1 and/or A2 values match.

For example, take

```
SELECT sampleID as Sample1, rs as rs1, A1 as A1_1, A2 as A2_1 FROM mytable where sampleID = "1001"  

SELECT sampleID as Sample2, rs as rs2, A1 as A1_2, A2 as A2_2 FROM mytable where sampleID = "1002"
```

How can I write a SELECT statement that takes the result of each SELECT above, joins at rs1 = rs2 and compares A1_1 with A1_2 and A2_1 with A2_2?

Comment: You said it yourself in question. Try join with giving the `same table alias. select t1.samleid as samp1,t2.sampleid as samp2,.....from mytable t1 join mytable t2 on t1. rs = t2.rs2 where ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use as self join here, to handle the comparisons:

```
SELECT
    t1.sampleID,
    t2.sampleID,
    t1.rs,
    t1.A1,
    t2.A1,
    (t1.A1 = t2.A1) AS A1_comp,
    t1.A2,
    t2.A2,
    (t1.A2 = t2.A2) AS A2_comp
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2
    ON t1.sampleID < t2.sampleID
WHERE
    t1.rs = t2.rs
ORDER BY
    t1.sampleID,
    t2.sampleID,
    t1.rs;
```

[image]

### Demo

The join condition requires that the `sampleID` on the left side of the join is strictly *less* than the one of the right side.  This ensures that we do not duplicate comparisons, or compare the same sample against itself.  We take advantage of selecting boolean equalities for the `A1` and `A2` values, which MySQL's syntax allows.  The aliases `A1_comp` and `A1_comp` will be 0 for a non match, and 1 for a match.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I would like to include a slightly modified version of an answer that was posted before. In this version only the non matching A1/A2 columns are shown as per the WHERE clause

```
SELECT 
A.rs1 as rs, A.Sample1_A1, A.Sample1_A2, B.Sample2_A1, B.Sample2_A2  
    from
    (
    SELECT sampleID as Sample1, rs as rs1, A1 as Sample1_A1, A2 as Sample1_A2 
    FROM mytable where sampleID = "1001" 
    )A left join
    ( 
    SELECT sampleID as Sample2, rs as rs2, A1 as Sample2_A1, A2 as Sample2_A2 
    FROM mytable where sampleID = "1002" 
    )B on A.rs1=B.rs2

where A.Sample1_A1 != B.Sample2_A1 or A.Sample1_A2 != B.Sample2_A2
```